# Система бекапа для папки на компьютере

Tags: python

У нас есть например папка с сохранениями. Как сделать программу,   которая при запуске будет сохранять определенную папку по определенному пути, либо загружать ее обратно.

Comment: это можно даже с помощью CMD сделать или bash. Ничего сложного

Comment: Рекурсивное копирование папки с содержимым можно сделать через `shutil.copytree`: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree

Comment: Вообще очень общий вопрос для короткого ответа.

Comment: А просто команда shutil.copy не пойдёт? Я просто прям крайне мало в питоне понимаю. Как це работает?)